# Image fully black after normalizing to [0,1]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to normalize an image to `[0,1]` like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/images/' + name)
norm_image = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

And when I try to show it:

```
cv2.imshow('normalized', norm_image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The image is fully black. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use cv2.imread to open an image, the default datatype is **integer**.

When you use cv2.normalize with no output datatype specified, the default is same type as the input, which is **integer** in this case.

It only makes sense to normalize an image between 0 - 1 using **float** values. Otherwise it's just 0 or 1.

Try adding the output datatype argument `dtype=cv2.CV_32F`

```
norm_image = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

Comment: NOTE: if the image is of type uint8, OpenCV interprets the range of 0 to 255 as black to white (float: 0.0 to 1.0). integer values 0 and 1 would be black and near-black.